# layer does not appear in qgis, after going to geoserver. Shp is working normally

Tags: postgis, qgis, geoserver

layer does not appear in qgis, after going to geoserver. Shp is working normally in the file, I'm trying to take everything to geoserver, I've already tried to make corrections to the features but it didn't help, follow the shp attached

I tried to fix the features to see the zoning but it didn't work (

[image]

Comment: please don't add text like error messages as an image, it makes it impossible for some users to read.